# How it is encode in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a webpage http://spys.one/en/anonymous-proxy-list/ to get a proxy address and port but as matter of fact, I can **scrape** address but not the port as it is contained inside javascript and encoded somehow take a look.
I'm using requests and beautiful soup for that.

```
'''python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url='http://spys.one/en/anonymous-proxy-list/'
r=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')'''
```

in head of webpage

```
<script type="text/javascript">o5y5=7474;l2h8=6751;b2v2=5357;p6g7=4218;m3k1=2225;h8x4=1220;q7u1=5086;t0o5=4972;j0a1=1545;w3l2=1788;d4j0g7=0^o5y5;j0r8o5=1^l2h8;t0h8c3=2^b2v2;n4k1b2=3^p6g7;x4b2m3=4^m3k1;m3d4z6=5^h8x4;c3e5e5=6^q7u1;s9x4a1=7^t0o5;v2s9i9=8^j0a1;h8z6n4=9^w3l2;</script>
```

in body of webpage

```
document.write("<font class=spy2>:<\/font>"+(n4k1b2^p6g7)+(h8z6n4^w3l2)+(x4b2m3^m3k1)+(d4j0g7^o5y5)+(m3d4z6^h8x4))
```

the output result is ":3905" on the original webpage.

Comment: That feels like intentional obfuscation for literally this reason. To stop simple web-crawlers from gathering the information.

Comment: but how I decode it in python .. I understand it is done just for this purpose somehow..

Comment: you could use selenium so all the java events are performned then you can just scrap the port number from the html directly

Comment: isn't there any way to resolve this without using selenium, can't I build a dictionary in python to decode it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hard to do without rendering the page first, I was able to get the data in selenium:

```py
url = 'http://spys.one/en/anonymous-proxy-list/'
driver.get(url)

table = [[col.text
          for col in row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')]
         for row in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr[contains(@class, "spy1x")]')]

data = [{k: v
         for k, v in zip(table[0], row)}
        for row in table[1:]]        

import json
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "45.76.83.163:17001",
        "Proxy type": "HTTP",
        "Anonymity*": "HIA",
        "Country (city)": "Germany (Frankfurt am Main)",
        "Hostname/ORG": "playbizz.ru (AS-CHOOPA)",
        "Latency**": "11.033",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "58% (7) -"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "103.117.23.33:33111",
        "Proxy type": "HTTP",
        "Anonymity*": "HIA",
        "Country (city)": "India (New Delhi)",
        "Hostname/ORG": "103.117.23.33 (Touch Net India Pvt. Ltd.)",
        "Latency**": "7.626",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "new -"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "124.219.176.139:39589",
        "Proxy type": "HTTP",
        "Anonymity*": "HIA",
        "Country (city)": "Japan (Tokyo)",
        "Hostname/ORG": "p7cdbb08b.tokyff01.ap.so-net.ne.jp (So-net Entertainment Corporation)",
        "Latency**": "12.201",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "43% (255) -"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "2.186.13.72:30339",
        "Proxy type": "HTTP",
        "Anonymity*": "HIA",
        "Country (city)": "Iran",
        "Hostname/ORG": "2.186.13.72 (Iran Telecommunication Company PJS)",
        "Latency**": "7.754",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "67% (2) +"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "40.119.154.217:80",
        "Proxy type": "HTTP",
        "Anonymity*": "ANM",
        "Country (city)": "Netherlands (Amsterdam) !!!",
        "Hostname/ORG": "40.119.154.217 (MICROSOFT-CORP-MSN-AS-BLOCK)",
        "Latency**": "0.224",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "new +"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "139.101.93.137:80",
        "Proxy type": "HTTP",
        "Anonymity*": "HIA",
        "Country (city)": "Japan (Kizugawa)",
        "Hostname/ORG": "user-137093101139.kinet-tv.ne.jp (Kintetsu Cable Network Co., Ltd.)",
        "Latency**": "10.217",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "8% (7) -"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "101.51.141.46:37858",
        "Proxy type": "HTTPS",
        "Anonymity*": "HIA",
        "Country (city)": "Thailand (Bangkok)",
        "Hostname/ORG": "node-rvy.pool-101-51.dynamic.totinternet.net (TOT Public Company Limited)",
        "Latency**": "2.807",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "45% (72) -"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "45.235.163.35:33265",
        "Proxy type": "HTTPS",
        "Anonymity*": "HIA",
        "Country (city)": "Brazil !!!",
        "Hostname/ORG": "45-235-163-35.nortenettelecom.com.br (norte.net telecomunicacoes me)",
        "Latency**": "7.072",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "29% (20) -"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "51.68.228.131:80",
        "Proxy type": "HTTP",
        "Anonymity*": "ANM",
        "Country (city)": "France",
        "Hostname/ORG": "vps-7d8ac4c6.vps.ovh.net (OVH SAS)",
        "Latency**": "0.112",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "100% (44) +"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "15.165.112.193:3128",
        "Proxy type": "HTTP",
        "Anonymity*": "ANM",
        "Country (city)": "South Korea (Incheon) !!!",
        "Hostname/ORG": "ec2-15-165-112-193.ap-northeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com (AMAZON-02)",
        "Latency**": "5.233",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "54% (69) -"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "72.250.28.64:36851",
        "Proxy type": "HTTPS",
        "Anonymity*": "HIA",
        "Country (city)": "United States",
        "Hostname/ORG": "72.250.28.64 (T-MOBILE-AS21928)",
        "Latency**": "11.472",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "47% (421) -"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "217.61.21.73:3128",
        "Proxy type": "HTTP",
        "Anonymity*": "ANM",
        "Country (city)": "United Kingdom (Slough)",
        "Hostname/ORG": "host73-21-61-217.static.arubacloud.com (ArubaCloud Limited)",
        "Latency**": "0.24",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "100% (8) +"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "185.44.229.227:34930",
        "Proxy type": "HTTP",
        "Anonymity*": "HIA",
        "Country (city)": "Armenia",
        "Hostname/ORG": "host-227.229.44.185.ucom.am (Ucom LLC)",
        "Latency**": "7.745",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "56% (254) -"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "176.63.205.248:54621",
        "Proxy type": "HTTP",
        "Anonymity*": "HIA",
        "Country (city)": "Hungary (Sopron)",
        "Hostname/ORG": "catv-176-63-205-248.catv.broadband.hu (Liberty Global B.V.)",
        "Latency**": "8.906",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "29% (22) -"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "41.217.219.49:38114",
        "Proxy type": "HTTP",
        "Anonymity*": "HIA",
        "Country (city)": "Malawi (Lilongwe)",
        "Hostname/ORG": "41.217.219.49 (SKYBAND)",
        "Latency**": "3.748",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "49% (21) -"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "202.154.180.53:48049",
        "Proxy type": "HTTP",
        "Anonymity*": "HIA",
        "Country (city)": "Indonesia (Jakarta)",
        "Hostname/ORG": "202.154.180.53 (PT INDONESIA COMNETS PLUS)",
        "Latency**": "13.436",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "34% (10) -"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "170.81.141.249:37081",
        "Proxy type": "HTTPS",
        "Anonymity*": "HIA",
        "Country (city)": "Mexico (Aguascalientes)",
        "Hostname/ORG": "170.81.141.249 (NUEVA RED INTERNET DE MEXICO S DE RL DE CV)",
        "Latency**": "10.191",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "50% (3) -"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "197.89.175.235:8080",
        "Proxy type": "HTTP (Squid)",
        "Anonymity*": "ANM",
        "Country (city)": "South Africa (Wellington) !!!",
        "Hostname/ORG": "197-89-175-235.dsl.mweb.co.za (OPTINET)",
        "Latency**": "3.726",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "57% (17) -"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "159.203.82.173:3128",
        "Proxy type": "HTTP",
        "Anonymity*": "ANM",
        "Country (city)": "United States (Clifton)",
        "Hostname/ORG": "rdcproxy.sebpo.net (DIGITALOCEAN-ASN)",
        "Latency**": "15.455",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "37% (64) +"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "13.125.52.156:3128",
        "Proxy type": "HTTP",
        "Anonymity*": "ANM",
        "Country (city)": "South Korea (Incheon) !!!",
        "Hostname/ORG": "ec2-13-125-52-156.ap-northeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com (AMAZON-02)",
        "Latency**": "7.663",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "100% (2) +"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "37.57.15.43:33761",
        "Proxy type": "HTTP",
        "Anonymity*": "HIA",
        "Country (city)": "Ukraine (Kharkiv)",
        "Hostname/ORG": "43.15.57.37.triolan.net (Content Delivery Network Ltd)",
        "Latency**": "11.894",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "52% (253) -"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "34.105.41.225:3128",
        "Proxy type": "HTTP (Squid)",
        "Anonymity*": "ANM",
        "Country (city)": "United States",
        "Hostname/ORG": "225.41.105.34.bc.googleusercontent.com (GOOGLE)",
        "Latency**": "9.458",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "67% (6) -"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "65.152.119.226:39408",
        "Proxy type": "HTTP",
        "Anonymity*": "HIA",
        "Country (city)": "United States (Denver)",
        "Hostname/ORG": "65.152.119.226 (CENTURYLINK-US-LEGACY-QWEST)",
        "Latency**": "3.001",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "22% (22) -"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "12.69.91.226:80",
        "Proxy type": "HTTP",
        "Anonymity*": "ANM",
        "Country (city)": "United States (Reno)",
        "Hostname/ORG": "12.69.91.226 (ATT-INTERNET4)",
        "Latency**": "10.76",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "35% (24) -"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "199.115.147.193:42760",
        "Proxy type": "HTTPS",
        "Anonymity*": "HIA",
        "Country (city)": "United States (Portsmouth) !!!",
        "Hostname/ORG": "199.115.147.193 (TELCOM-SYSTEMS)",
        "Latency**": "3.558",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "26% (8) +"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "125.26.108.170:61637",
        "Proxy type": "HTTP",
        "Anonymity*": "HIA",
        "Country (city)": "Thailand (Taling Chan)",
        "Hostname/ORG": "node-lgq.pool-125-26.dynamic.totinternet.net (TOT Public Company Limited)",
        "Latency**": "4.715",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "38% (151) +"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "34.125.152.121:3128",
        "Proxy type": "HTTPS (Squid)",
        "Anonymity*": "ANM",
        "Country (city)": "United States",
        "Hostname/ORG": "121.152.125.34.bc.googleusercontent.com (GOOGLE)",
        "Latency**": "12.601",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "67% (6) -"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "34.125.5.58:3128",
        "Proxy type": "HTTP (Squid)",
        "Anonymity*": "ANM",
        "Country (city)": "United States",
        "Hostname/ORG": "58.5.125.34.bc.googleusercontent.com (GOOGLE)",
        "Latency**": "12.049",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "60% (6) +"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "103.83.36.55:5836",
        "Proxy type": "HTTP",
        "Anonymity*": "ANM",
        "Country (city)": "United States (Asheville)",
        "Hostname/ORG": "dahit.substands.com (Medha Hosting)",
        "Latency**": "7.581",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "27% (4) -"
    },
    {
        "Proxy address:port": "3.136.226.213:3128",
        "Proxy type": "HTTP",
        "Anonymity*": "ANM",
        "Country (city)": "United States (Columbus)",
        "Hostname/ORG": "ec2-3-136-226-213.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com (AMAZON-02)",
        "Latency**": "8.172",
        "Speed***": "",
        "Uptime": "",
        "Check date (GMT+03)": "50% (9) +"
    }
]
```

Comment: you have to install selenium webdriver, you can do it all from google colab too which makes things easier for one-rime operations

Comment: here is the colab notebook https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1HMjaVdgzFZz5vz9qy_w9g4_A3RCL0DnE?usp=sharing and a github gist https://gist.github.com/bherbruck/393a73cc749e1fd3c480f87ee87c5289